# Create an infinite loop on field value

Tags: javascript, loops, infinite-loop

So im creating a shop on bigcartel and i want to add a free delivery option. but they currently dont allow you to add it to spercific countries. I am currently adding coding to show a div or alert the user when their total is over £85 and they select UK as their desitination.

ATM i think my code wont loop.. well it dont seem to :/ 
I need it to loop so that it checks the value of the total price when customers add or subtract items .. whicvh would + or - the total amount.

i HAVE

```
 var amount = {{ cart.total }} ;
 var country = {{ store.country | country_select }};

 t=setTimeout("checkprice()",10);

 function checkprice()
  {
 if(amount >= 85 || country = 45 )
 { 
   alert('OVER 85!') ;

  }
  else
  {
alert('monkeys')
  }
}
```

## EDIT! 08/Feb/12

as suggested by @kolink: i have come up with this,,,

```
  //----get variables--
 var amount = {{ cart.total }};
 var moose = document.getElementById("country");

    function freedel() 
    {
      if (moose = 42 || amount >= 85 )  
    { 
        document.getElementById("moose").style.visibility='visible';     
     }
          else 
     {
      alert('WRONG!')
      }
      }
```

the HTML being:

```
        <div id="moose" style="visibility:hidden;"> dfgsdgfdsg</div>
```

and

```
    <h3 id="cart_price" onChange="freedel()">{{ cart.total | money_with_sign  }}</h3>
```

Comment: You're right it won't loop - there's no loops at all in that code.

Comment: Why don't you just set it to check whenever a user adds or substracts anything rather than TRYING to loop

Comment: not only that but for it to function you'd have to call it every time the cart total is updated or the country was change.

Comment: @Henesnarfel up vote for getting it in (the answer) before me ;-)

Comment: @Henesnarfel  how would i go about doing that? - the thing is... the amount changes dynamicly.. you dont refresh total. if i reduced the quanity the amount changes automaticly.

Comment: @WednesdayMan I'm assuming you have add and remove buttons for manipulating the cart.  If so you just need to bind click events to those that check the total after the actions are done to see if anything needs done.  JQuery can accomplish this pretty easily.

Answer (score 1):

You tell it to check the price 10 milliseconds after the page loads, then you never tell it to run again.

And if your code worked, it would show the alert, then another 10 milliseconds later (which is nowhere near enough time to fix the issue).

What you should do is add `checkprice();` to your code wherever you update `cart.total` or `store.country`. Maybe an `onChange` event can help you there.

As a side note, never ever use a string in `setTimeout`. Pass the function itself (ie. `setTimeout(checkprice,10);`) or an anonymous function (is. `setTimeout(function() {checkprice();},10);` instead.

Comment: i have currently put this..
      `//----get variables--
 var amount = {{ cart.total }};
 var moose = document.getElementById("country");

    function freedel() 
    {
      if (moose = 42 || amount >= 85 )  
    { 
        document.getElementById("moose").style.visibility='visible';     
     }
          else 
     {
      alert('WRONG!')
      }
      }`  

check above for rest of code